# Merge two bitfields according a bitmask

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitmask, ansi-c

I wondering whether is it possible to use bit operations to merge two bitfields according a bitmask?
For example I have two values, and a bitmask:

```
char mask = 0x29; // 0010 1001
char a = 0x9;     // 0000 1001 original value
char b = 0xE8;    // 1110 1000 modified value
```

And I want to set the bits in b to the value of a, according the bitmask. Only 3 bits would be affected.

```
char val = 0xC9;  // 1100 1001 value
```

So how can I do with only bit operations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, clear off the bits that are *set* in the mask from `b`. Then, clear off the bits that are *not set* in the mask from `a`. Finally, `OR` the two results together:

```
b = (b & ~mask) | (a & mask);
```

The tilde `~` operator produces the negated mask. `AND`ing with `~mask` zeroes out the bits of `b` that are set in the mask.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like:

```
b &= ~mask;       /* Clear bits set in mask. */
b |= (mask & a);  /* Add bits set both in a and in mask. */
```

Also, you might want to use `unsigned` types instead of the inconclusive `char`.

Answer (score 4):

```
val = a ^ ((a ^ b) & mask);
```

Also works. Usually that doesn't really help as such, but there are circumstances in which it may. If `a` and `b` are both constants, for example, it can be simplified more than the normal formula can.

Comment: This is generally one operation shorter than the obvious method.
https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#MaskedMerge